# bzgrep not printing the file name

Tags: unix, grep

```
find . -name '{fileNamePattern}*.bz2' | xargs -n 1 -P 3 bzgrep -H "{patternToSearch}"
```

I am using the command above to find out a .bz2 file from set of files that have a pattern that I am looking for. It does go through the files because I can see the pattern that I am trying to find being printed on the console but I don't see the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `bzgrep` script (for example [this version](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bzip2/bzip2-29/bzip2/bzgrep) for OS X) you will see that it pipes the output from `bzip2` through `grep`. That process loses the original filenames. `grep` never sees them so it cannot print them out (despite your `-H` flag).

Something like this should do, not exactly what you want but something similar. (You could get the prefix you were expecting by piping the output from `bzgrep` into `sed`/`awk` but that's a bit less simple of a command to write out.)

```
find . -name '{fileNamePattern}*.bz2' -printf '### %p\n' -exec bzgrep "{patternToSearch}" {} \;
```

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `bzgrep` or output the file names as "header" lines yourself.

Comment: I didn't get you. I do not have any other utility to parse the bz2 files so I have to use bzgrep
But I didnt understand your solution to get file names.

Comment: You can un-bzip them yourself and then `grep` on them which will let `-H` work or you can use a script as the command for `xargs` to run which prints out the argument filename before running `grep` on it (or similar). Actually, using `-exec` is easier (but doesn't get you parallel execution).

Answer (score 0):

I printed the file name through echo command and xargs.

```
find . -name "*bz2" | parallel -j 128 echo -n {}\" \" | xargs bzgrep {pattern}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Etan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) is very close with his answer: `grep` indeed does not show the filename when only dealing with one file, so you can make `grep` believe he's looking into multiple files, just by adding the `NULL` file, so the command becomes:

```
find . -name '{fileNamePattern}*.bz2' -printf '### %p\n' 
  -exec bzgrep "{patternToSearch}" {} /dev/null \;
```

(It's a dirty trick but it's helping me already for more than 15 years :-) )